# 0 value is returned on success result in ajax in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(course_id, subject_id) {
        var site_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
        var ajaxurl = site_url + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        alert(ajaxurl);
        var data = {
            action: 'example_ajax_request'
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'insert_data_customtable' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request','insert_data_customtable');

function insert_data_customtable()
{
    $result="hi";
    echo $result;
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you elaborate the question a little bit. You have passed parameters to functions where are from they coming.

**echo json_encode($result);**

**echo $result;**

it will display the value stored in it

Comment: echo json_encode($result);
        die(); you can also use this instead of die. exit(0);

Comment: json_encode is usually used for sql query. if answer is fine then mark it as correct answer

Comment: i have done changes as  you suggested but still not getting solution.

Comment: that 0 value is returned from wp-ajax.php. At the end of file there is die(0);

Comment: now i got the solution as i written insert_data_customtable() function in function.php